# How do I view Jupyter Notebook git diffs in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, git, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, diff

How do I view Jupyter Notebook git diffs in Visual Studio Code?

Some sources seem to suggest this feature is available now, but I only see the diff of the raw file.
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_49#_notebooks

I'm using the latest Visual Studio Code version, 1.62.3. I'm using the Python extension and "native notebooks". I'm not sure whether adding `notebook.diff.enablePreview: true` to `settings.json` is necessary, but in any case, it has no effect.

Update: I can see the readable diff when I select "Show Changes" on the notebook in the Source Control sidebar. The problem arises when I select "Click to View Diff" on a notebook at a specific commit in Git Graph. Perhaps it's a Git Graph problem -- what's the best workaround?

[image]

Comment: The default value of `notebook.diff.enablePreview` is true, you need not edit it. Sorry, but I am a little confused about `only see the diff of the raw file`, could you provide a screenshot of it? And what's the meaning of `native notebooks`? Have you installed the Python extension? Thanks.

Comment: Notebooks used to be a separate extension, but now they're integrated with VS Code and available via the Python extension, which as I mentioned I have installed. "Diff of the raw file" means the diff of the hard-to-read json data that notebook files use behind the scenes, instead of a nice view of the changes between the cells, shown in the link.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as it works well on my computer, only after I have clicked the `Open Text Diff Editor` button on the top-right then it will display the raw file. So, could you provide a screenshot of it?

Comment: I added a picture. I believe this is the standard VS code git diff view.

Answer (score 0):

In the link you provided, the feature is controlled by setting `notebook.diff.enablePreview` to true

Comment: Have you confirmed for yourself that this works? I've already tried that, it had no effect.

Comment: simply process of elimination. add this detail to the question and I'll delete the answer

Answer (score 0):

It works well on my computer, and it looks different from yours, how do you compare them? Could you attach a screenshot of the sidebar?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ah, interesting. When I go to the git sidebar and select "Open changes" on a changed notebook, I see the view you are seeing here. My main use case is viewing a notebook diff at any previous commit. What is the best way to do that? I was using Git Graph and selecting "Click to View Diff" on the notebook in the commit.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still have the issue. I'm using the git history add-on and had the same problem you described. But, The issue was solved when I **unchecked** the option "Enable Preview Editors" on the top-right of the screen. I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still helpful, but I had the same problem as you.

If you compare diff from the gitgraph (in red box), the comparing files are opened like JSON files. A workaround I just discovered is to compare the files by clicking in the file history from the source control button (in green). This way opens the files correctly to be compared.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSYAu.png)